# Pandas - CSV to Dataframe (Column encoded with Base64)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, base64

The following code is used to ingest firewall logs from a csv into a dataframe using Pandas.

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/alistairgillespie/Documents/Projects/COMP5310/Akamai Data/FINAL/data.csv', dtype = {"_time": str, "city": str,"country": str,"lat": str,"long": str,"region": str,"UA": str,"bytes": str,"cliIP": str,"reqHost": str, "reqMethod": str, "reqPath": str,"reqPort": str,"respCT": str,"respLen": str,"status": str,"referer": str,"date": str,"conn": str,"denyData": str,"denyRules": str,"policy": str,"ruleSet": str,"warnRules": str,"warnData": str,"warnSlrs": str,"warnTags": str})
```

* Excuse the long line of columns

Once in the dataframe, I am wanting to iterate over each row and decode the 'denyData' column fields (if not NaN) using unquote and base64decode function calls. I am trying to do this with the following code:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print(pd.notnull(row))
    temp = parse.unquote(row['denyData'])
    new = base64.b64decode(temp)
    df2.loc[i, 'denyData'] = new
```

The following error is produced:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

What is the correct way of processing byte columns from csv into Pandas dataframes and is this the correct approach to cleaning such data? An example of the data follows.

[image: Example of the column with encoded data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `if-else`, because error obviously means cannot process `NaN`s:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print(pd.notnull(row))
    if pd.notnull(row):
        df.loc[i, 'denyData'] = base64.b64decode(parse.unquote(row['denyData']))
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'denyData'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Great, this works. However, it takes a long time to process the 850,000 rows. Does pandas have a more efficient way to process a column like this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It is not implemented.